# How can I get rid of Unicode Encode Error while trying to output web scraping result in a .txt file

Tags: python, unicode

**following is my code in python for the scraping and output efforts**

```
html = urlopen("http://www.imdb.com/news/top")
wineReviews = BeautifulSoup(html)
lines = []
    for headLine in imdbNews.findAll("h2"): 
    #headLine.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    imdb_news = headLine.get_text()
    lines.append(imdb_news)
    #f = open("output.txt", "a")
    #f.write(imdb_news)
    #f.close()
```

**The #s have been my attempts on trying to get rid of the Unicode errors but it just results into more errors that I can't seem to wrap my head around. Current code results in the following output:**

```
[u'Warner Bros. Brings \u2018Wonder Woman,\u2019 \u2018Suicide Squad,\u2019 \u2018Fantastic Beasts\u2019 to Comic-Con',
 u"\u2018Ghostbusters': Is There a Post-Credit Scene?",
 u'Javier Bardem Eyed for Frankenstein Role in Universal\u2019s Monster Universe (Exclusive)',
 u'\u2018Battlefield\u2019 Video Game Being Developed for TV Series by Paramount Television & Anonymous Content',
 u'\u2018Ghostbusters\u2019 Review Roundup: Critics Generally Positive On Female-Led Blockbuster',
 u'\u2018Assassin\u2019s Creed\u2019 Movie Won\u2019t Make Money, Ubisoft Chief Says',
 u"Fargo Taps The Leftovers' Carrie Coon as Female Lead in Season 3",
 u'Ridley Scott Long-Time Collaborator Julie Payne Dies at 64',
 u'Ridley Scott Longtime Collaborator Julie Payne Dies at 64',
 u'15 Highest Paid Music Stars of 2016, From The Weeknd to Taylor Swift (Photos)',
 u'South Africa\u2019s Pubcaster Draws Ire From Demonstrators, the Government',
 u'Jerry Greer, Son of Country Music Singer Craig Morgan, Dies at 19',
 u'Queen Latifah Says Racism Is "Still Alive and Kicking" at VH1 Hip Hop Honors',
 u'Jerry Greer, Son of Country Singer Craig Morgan, Found Dead After Boating Accident',
 u'[Watch] Emmy Awards movie/mini slugfest: \u2018The People v. O.J. Simpson\u2019 and \u2018Fargo\u2019 battle for the win',
 u'Amanda Evans Wraps Videovision\u2019s Thriller \u2018Serpent\u2019',
 u'\u2018Oslo\u2019 Theater Review: The Handshake That Shook the World',
 u'\u2018The Bachelorette\u2019 Recap: JoJo Tames Some Wild Horses',
 u'Disney Accelerator Names 9 Startups to Participate in 2016 Mentorship Program',
 u'Karlovy Vary Film Review: \u2018The Teacher\u2019',
 u'Top News',
 u'Movie News',
 u'TV News',
 u'Celebrity News']
```

**How do I get rid of the u' and \u2018 , \u2019 etc..? and get my results in a txt file**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Since you don't want the `\u` characters in your string.
This should work :

```
html = urlopen("http://www.imdb.com/news/top")
wineReviews = BeautifulSoup(html)
lines = []
    for headLine in imdbNews.findAll("h2"): 
        imdb_news = headLine.get_text()
        lines.append(imdb_news.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        f = open("output.txt", "a")
        f.write(imdb_news.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        f.close()
```

i.e,

encode the `Unicode` characters to `ASCII` before writing to the file.

What you were doing wrong is this :

```
headLine.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

this will not modify the `headLine`, you need to assign this value to `headLine`, like this :

```
headLine = headLine.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 s = u'\u2018Battlefield\u2019'.encode('utf-8')
 with open("some_file", "w") as f:
     f.write(s)
```

just add .encode('utf-8') to your strings before writing them to a file